# How to send shutdown command from computer a to computer b if they are intranet in C#

Tags: c#

I am not asking how to code it

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

I am asking if 
I made a user interface to detect the computers in the network. Knowing their ip and having domain admin priveledges. How do I send a signal to execute my c# .exe ?

Comment: Not at all sure why this question merited the downvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line is

```
shutdown /m \\<MACHINE NAME OR IP>
```

so you can use:

```
Process.Start("shutdown",string.Format(@"/s /t 0 /m \\{0}",machineIp));
```

Comment: i tried this also shutdown -i and thank you for your help very nice.

Answer (score 2):

That would be so wrong to be able to execute applications remotely, right? :) I think best method is to write your C# executable as a background service. To send remote messages, WCF is very useful. Here are the links you need:

How to write a background service in c#: (you may already know it, i send the link just in case)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/csharpsvclesson1.aspx

About WCF: (which you will need to call functions from a remote computer)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

edit: i didn't know about shutdown command's extra parameters. if that method works, it's much easier of course.

Comment: you apparently missed the part of the  OP's question where he mentions having admin privileges on the domain controller.  That means the current user of the app has user-admin rights on every machine in the domain.  Doing this sort of thing is perfectly possible, and, for example, PowerShell allows for remote operations of this sort with ease.

Comment: but the question at the end was "How do I send a signal to execute my c# .exe ?". that's what i was focused on. i didn't know about the shutdown.exe's additional parameters etc.

Comment: sure, but as I said, [PowerShell supports this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188734/using-powershell-on-one-computer-to-execute-a-powershell-script-on-another) out of the box.  So it's easy to tap into.

Comment: i am looking into powershell because of WUA which is something i am interested in for work.

Comment: I know how to create a service but what is the command to execute the .exe via wcf? I mean, once I have two endspoints A and B how to I tell B to open .exe from point A